# Put Jade local variable in tag attribute

Tags: node.js, pug

I want to put Jade variable in tag attribute but it isn't evaluated.

`a(href="/logout/#{user.name}")`

Comment: That's strange because ^this^ works perfectly for me...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You could use:

```
a(href='/logout/'+user.name)
```

Comment: What if the variable is {{$obj->val}} (php blade template). Then anyway we must use brackets to avoid auto escaping but it will not be evaluated.