# passing dynamic i18n resources from node to jade

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug, i18next

I want to have a custom error page shown to the user in case of an error.
My problem is, that it has to be i18n-ed.

## Idea:

Validate in node -> if not accepted -> `res.render('error', {message: errorMessageNameTooLong});` -> in jade, render that to a placeholder, which translates the errors from my translation.json `p(data-i18n='errorMessageNameTooLong')`

## Problem:

How can i pass the message, so that the VALUE will be the data-i18n attribute in jade?

So far, i'm stuck with pre-formatting my jade template to `p(data-i18n="errormsg")`
but that makes it impossible to display (i.e. translate) more than one error.
I want the `p` to have a custom data-i18n attribute, depending on what error it actually is...

i hope that is understandable :D

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Put Jade local variable in tag attribute](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081534/put-jade-local-variable-in-tag-attribute)

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is one way, but there's an easier one:

`p(data-i18n=errMsg)`

Just put the variable after the `=` without the `""`

Check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081534/put-jade-local-variable-in-tag-attribute) for an in-depth explanation or check the [official documentation](http://jade-lang.com/reference/attributes/).

Answer (score 0):

Ok i actually just found it out myself.. and it was absolutely straightforward.

## solution:

router.post('/register'):

```
if(username.length > MAX_USERNAME_LENGTH) {
  res.render('error', {title: "error.error", errMsg: "error.nameTooLong"});
}
```

error.jade:

```
block content
  h1(data-i18n="#{title}")
  p(data-i18n="#{errMsg}")
```