# How to inject a value inside a string in pug

Tags: javascript, pug, pugjs

Hello guys I am trying to inject a value inside a pug html attribute. I can not seem to find any documentation on how to do this. Here's my code

```
input(type='hidden', name='country', value='#{val.snippet.id.videoId}')
```

as you can imagine `val.snippet.id.videoId` is just a javascript variable I am passing from my server side. So I want to set the value attribute to that variable. Would really appreciate if someone points me to the right direction.

Comment: try just input(type='hidden', name='country', value=val.snippet.id.videoId)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081534/put-jade-local-variable-in-tag-attribute

Comment: @impregnablefiend yes you are a life saver :)

Comment: @Shadid you are welcome, i've posted an answer - plz accept it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wouldn't something like this work?

```
input(type='hidden', name='country', value=val.snippet.id.videoId)
```

As far as I remember you don't need to interpolate variables in attributes, just use them after `=`.

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to interpolate (in attributes) since Pug 0.1.0 (Jade 2.x) as well as I know.

So, your solution is just:

```
input(type='hidden', name='country', value=val.snippet.id.videoId)
```